# How to implement login activity that available in all activity. android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

In my application I have more that 20 activities and I want to ask for log in on particular operation on all activity if user is not logged in but not getting any idea where to start. I am using three method for login first my website login,second google and third is facebook. User can pick any to log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an activity which will contain function that would be common to all activity like login handler and extend that activity from your existing activities.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for validity of the sessionId before launching anything. If valid, launch activity. Else, launch Login page.

Comment: i have tab activity too that is causing problem actully.

Comment: What problem is the TabActivity causing?

Comment: problem is solved .
 actully tab was causing nested activity and as for login activity i had to use startactivity() for result.

Answer (score 0):

You can send broadcast, when you want to ask user for login. Then, in BroadcastReceiver you'll create your login activity, start it and wait for result (which also can be sent back by intent).